# Uniqueness of Density Operator

Tags: mathematics, textbook-and-exercises, density-matrix

I have been reading "**Introduction to Quantum Information Science**" by *Masahito Hayashi, Satoshi Ishizaka,Akinori Kawachi, Gen Kimura and Tomohiro Ogawa*; Springer Publication. I'm currently in the density operator section, page 96. There they are considering two ensemble states as follows $s_1 = \left\{ \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}; |0\rangle,|1\rangle \right\}$ and
$s_2 = \left\{ \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}; |+\rangle,|-\rangle \right\}$. Let there be a arbitary physical quantity be $A = \sum_a aP_a$ (Spectral Decomposition). Hence they are doing this:
$$ 
Pr(A=a|s_2) = \frac{1}{2} \langle+|P_a|+\rangle + \frac{1}{2} \langle-|P_a|-\rangle = \frac{1}{2} \langle0|P_a|0\rangle + \frac{1}{2} \langle1|P_a|1\rangle = Pr(A=a|s_1)\tag1
 $$
They are concluding that that the uniqueness of the states $s_1$ and $s_2$ are getting lost in equation (1), hence they are suggesting below form(2):
$$
Pr(A=a|s) = \sum_i p_iPr(A=a|\text{ }|\psi_i\rangle) = \sum_i p_i \langle\psi_i|P_a|\psi_i\rangle \tag2
$$
They are claiming that the above representation[2] is unique

> In order to get rid of non-uniqueness defect...

. But i cant understand how? To me both(1) & (2) are same. I'm adding the snapshot too.[image]

Comment: to which "representation" in particular are you referring to? Writing $\mathrm{Pr}(A=a|s)=\sum_i p_i \mathrm{Pr}(A=a| \psi_i)$?

Comment: @glS to the representation in the line number 5 from the top in the snapshot.

Comment: I don't really see anything that seems like a "representation" in the fifth line. I tried to answer based on the general idea of why two ensembles would lead to the same observed probabilities

Comment: @gls please give another look at the question, i've given equation numbers to explain it clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an ensemble as $\{(p_i,\psi_i)\}_i$, with $p_i$ probabilities and $\psi_i$ pure states. Let $\mathcal I_1\equiv \{(p_i,\psi_i)\}_i$ and $\mathcal I_2\equiv \{(q_i,\phi_i)\}_i$ be two such ensembles.
Suppose that
$$\sum_i p_i \lvert \psi_i\rangle\!\langle\psi_i\rvert
= \sum_i q_i \lvert \phi_i\rangle\!\langle\phi_i\rvert$$
(you can verify that this is the case in your example).

Your statement amounts to observing that, performing some measurement $A$, the probability of getting the outcome $a$ with the ensemble $\mathcal I_1$ is the same as that with the ensemble $\mathcal I_2$.

This probability reads, for $\mathcal I_1$,
$$\mathrm{Pr}(A=a|\mathcal I_1) = \sum_j p_j \mathrm{Pr}(A=a|\psi_j)
= \sum_j p_j \langle\psi_j|P_a|\psi_j\rangle
= \mathrm{Tr}\left(P_a \sum_j p_j |\psi_j\rangle\!\langle\psi_j|\right).\tag A$$
You similarly get for $\mathcal I_2$
$$\mathrm{Pr}(A=a|\mathcal I_2) = \mathrm{Tr}\left(P_a \sum_j q_j |\phi_j\rangle\!\langle\phi_j|\right).\tag B$$
But by assumption the sum in the parentheses of (A) and (B) is the same, hence the conclusion

Comment: What i was asking is that how equation [2] is "getting rid of the non-uniqueness" from the probability expression given earlier[1], which was, as stated by them, "non-unique" for $s_1$ and $s_2$?

Comment: because that expression gives identical results when you evaluate it in either ensemble

Comment: Then the claim "getting rid of the non-uniqueness" is wrong, am i right? Becoz the two ensembles are kinda similar in the probability terms? And (1) and (2) are same, right?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The claim is right, in that the two ensemble provide identical results, thus they are all equivalent, i.e. states can be represented uniquely

Comment: could you please describe what this phrase , "State can be represented uniquely" mean? Actually I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: @SaptarshiSahoo which part of the sentence exactly are you not clear about?